# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-xxxxxx>

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I currently work on a static website built on Vuepress. I have an error that shows when registering a Vue component in a .md file.

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-b86f6654149c6> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Page> at lib/default-theme/Page.vue
       <Layout> at lib/default-theme/Layout.vue
         <Root
```

It fails to mount the component and the components tree in Vue devtools only displays

```
<Page>
     <Content>
```

with nothing inside.

If I hit refresh though, the components are rendered correctly and I have what expected :

```
<Page>
     <VXXXXXXX>
         <Component1>
         <Component2>
```

Issue looks similar to what is referenced here : https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/1173 but I could not find a working solution.

For example, I have a `/docs/contact/README.md` that looks like:

```
---
title: a title
description: a description
pageClass: homepage subpage contact
headerText: Contact
blackSubText: some text
submitText: Envoyer
submitImage: /img/icons/green-arrow.png

---

<headerTextComponent/>

<formulaire type="contact" formId="/6db97999-f466-4250-aa47-bd6e96a6b520" :fields="['contactobject', 'message']"/>


<blog/>
```

and my above referenced custom components are in `/docs/.vuepress/components`, all being regular Vue components with a name property set.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem. However, after hours of googling and rebuilding **VuePress** I tried to access `http://127.0.0.1:8081` instead of `http://localhost:8081` - and it worked!

I assume it's a caching Problem or something like this - even without a service worker installed.